# Positioning widgets in a grid cell?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to position labels dynamically added to a grid. I'd like the label widgets in the 2nd column to all align to the right side of the column rather than the left. I've tried all kinds of alignment to no avail. So I've pared it back to this demo code At this stage I'm wondering if I can bind the label width to the column width and *then* use alignment. Or can I override on_size for the label and adjust it to the parent grid column?

[image: grid alignment demo]

Code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app            import App
from kivy.uix.label      import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.factory        import Factory

class AlignTestGridLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AlignTestGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def update( self, *args):
        for j in range(0,4):
            for i in range(0,4):
                newCell = Factory.GridEntry()
                newCell.text = 'text' + ( str(j) * (j + 1))
                self.ids.gridCalendar.add_widget( newCell )

class AlignTestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        AlignTest = AlignTestGridLayout()
        AlignTest.update()
        return AlignTest

if __name__ == '__main__':

    AlignTestApp().run()
```

KV

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<Widget>:
    # draw outlines for debugging only
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

<GridEntry@Label>:
    padding_x: 5
    font_size: 25
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: self.texture_size

<AlignTestGridLayout>:
    GridLayout:
        id: gridCalendar
        cols: 4
        rows: 4
        size: self.minimum_size
```

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. @ApuCoder got me closest. I would still have liked the grid, or it's columns, to shrink to the most compact or minimum size. I'll use some other method to get close to what I need. I learned from both answers 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `halign` property of `Label` to position its `text` but that has no effect when its size is bound to its `texture_size`. So in order to use that property you can bind only its `height` to its texture height and modify its `text_size`.

Also in that case you can restrict its parent layout, here `GridLayout`, in height by using `minimum_height` (also to restrict the `width` you can specify that explicitly or use `col_default_width` etc.).

With all this your modified code in `kvlang` would now look like,

```py
#:kivy 2.1.0

<Widget>:
    # draw outlines for debugging only
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

<GridEntry@Label>:
    padding_x: 5
    font_size: 25
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text_size: self.width, None

<AlignTestGridLayout>:
    cols: 1  # You must provide a value to at least one of `cols` and `rows`.
    GridLayout:
        id: gridCalendar
        cols: 4
        rows: 4
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

Now to alter labels' position in particular column you can modify the logic as,

```py
    def update( self, *args):
        for j in range(0,4):
            for i in range(0,4):
                newCell = Factory.GridEntry()
                newCell.halign = "right" if i == 1 else "left"
                newCell.text = 'text' + ( str(j) * (j + 1))
                self.ids.gridCalendar.add_widget( newCell )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the size of children depend on the column width and also use `minimum_size` for the `GridLayout`. You can see that it would lead to an infinite loop.

Also, your posted code should be printing a warning about not setting either `rows` or `cols` for the `AlignTestGridLayout` (even though they are set for the child `GridLayout`).

So, a few changes allow the `GridEntry` to fill its grid cell and use `halign` to do the positioning. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does this:

```
<Widget>:
    # draw outlines for debugging only
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
            dash_offset: 5
            dash_length: 3

<GridEntry@Label>:
    col: 0  # the column number for this GridEntry
    padding_x: 5
    font_size: 25
    # size_hint: (None, None)
    # size: self.texture_size  # allow entry to fill the grid cell
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'right' if self.col == 1 else 'left'  # alignment based on column number

<AlignTestGridLayout>:
    cols: 1  # at least cols or rows should be defined
    size_hint: 0.75, 0.75  # control size of grid here
    GridLayout:
        id: gridCalendar
        cols: 4
        rows: 4
        # size: self.minimum_size  # cannot use minimum_size unless sizes of children are specified explicitly
```

And a small change to provide the column number to the `GridEntry`:

```
class AlignTestGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def update( self, *args):
        for j in range(0,4):
            for i in range(0,4):
                newCell = Factory.GridEntry()
                newCell.col = i  # set column number for this newCell
                newCell.text = 'text' + ( str(j) * (j + 1))
                self.ids.gridCalendar.add_widget( newCell )
```